# Overriding bootstrap table-striped rows with jquery onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

hello everyone.
I've used bootstrap 4 table classes to build the table shown in the image, including the table-striped class which gives the table it's alternate row bg-colors. I've then used a jquery function to give the highlighted row it's deep blue bg-color.

everything works as expected, except that the bg-color gotten from the jquery function, does not override the alternate (gray colored) rows of the table, it only works on the white colored rows. Is there a way to make this work? i.e make the function override the color of the gray colored rows as well as the white ones? I don't want to have to stop using the bootstrap table-striped class.

below is the jquery function I'm using:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function(){
     var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
     $("tbody tr").removeClass("highlight");
     if(!selected)
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: Did your try `!important` for your `highlight` class?

Comment: You're trying to override highlight's of the hover elements and trying to set the class using clicks. Try `hover` function instead.

Comment: Try this link below.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/fhh8yz6z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use link to your CSS file after link to the bootstrap CSS. For example:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mytheme.css">
</head>
```

Note, you could add any query string to your CSS-file URL to avoid сaching problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mytheme.css?version=new">
```

Also you can use `!important` rules in your CSS as a last resort.

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="col-xs-1">
      <col class="col-xs-7"> </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="highlight">
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>highlited row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Text</th>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: that's brilliant @Alexander,  the !important value worked, but re-arranging the link references did'nt.
anyway thank you for your help